# Best Way to Display Large Amounts of Data in Django

Tags: python, json, django, database

I have a few hundred thousand rows of data that I would like to display in Django. I would like to be able to Search and filter the data. Currently, the data is in JSON format but I'm not really concerned about that I could easily change it to a DB if needed.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I need this external facing so it can't just be a code interface!

Comment: You could use [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) to dump the JSON out as an API

Comment: @gtlambert But how would I then display that data so that it's searchable and filterable!

Comment: Use a client side library such as react.js

Comment: @HåkenLid So would I use the JsonResponse API to give the data to client side?